# aborting an fopen() PHP call

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fopen

My current project involves a PHP script that uploads files to AWS S3 and I've been using a `fopen()` function to do this. However, if the user wants to abandon the upload, how can I halt the `fopen()` function? I've tried `exit()` and `die()` but they're simply getting queued in Apache until after `fopen()` completes meaning until after the file has uploaded to S3 (which could be minutes). The only way I can cancel this is by shutting down Apache which will obviously never fly in production.

Ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: Here's the code I'm working with for the upload:

```
        // Upload a file.
        $result = $s3client->putObject(array(
            'ACL'       => 'public-read', // so the users can see the information in S3
            'Bucket'    => AWS_BUCKET,
            'Key'       => '/files/'.sha1($file_id).'.'.$file_ext,
            'Body'      => fopen($file, 'r+')
            )
        );
```

Comment: how does the user indicate he wishes to abandon? The script is already running, so the user indicating anything would happen in a second script

Comment: I made an ajax call to die, exit, or fclose but it's getting queued instead of executing and thus halting the fopen() which is the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.

When uploading a file to PHP, the PHP script is only started once the entire upload is completed. This is handled by your webserver (Apache) that gets the POST request with the uploaded files. Once the webserver received the entire request (including the uploaded files), apache starts PHP and passes the request (and the uploaded files) to it.

So once the first line of your PHP code is run, it means the entire file has already been uploaded. Trying to abandon the upload from within the PHP code is therefore too late.

What you can do is send the file(s) in chunks. But it would need some client side scripting to accomplish this. [Here](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) is a plugin you can maybe use.

Or another blunt way to maybe do this is to just add an extra button on the previous page (the one used to select the file that should be uploaded, and start to upload). Assuming this page is still being displayed during the upload, you can have this extra button go to any other page, thus making the browser abandon the upload to the web server.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I'm actually using jQuery File Upload (JFU) for the queueing process on the front-end so I'll take a look at the maxChunkSize param and see if that can help me manage the UX of the process a bit better. I'm not using the PHP uploader that is packaged with the plugin since S3 didn't seem to place nice with it but maybe I'll have to have a second look at that since I'm assuming the maxChunkSize correlates directly with JFU's post request

Comment: @dbadness Just so I understand fully. You upload from a browser to your script. And then your script uploads the uploaded file again to the AWS S3 server? Or does your script already reside on the AWS S3 server? Also, when do you want to be able to abandon? During the upload from the browser to your script? Or when uploading from your script to the AWS S3 server?

Comment: The file goes from browser to the tmp folder in Apache with jQuery File Upload and then redirects to another script that runs a foreach() loop to get the files from the tmp folder to S3. I'd love to get the S3 upload happening in the jQuery File Upload PHP uploader but it's just not happening. That's a topic for another question however.

Answer (score 1):

Try [fclose](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php)

```
$handle = fopen('somefile.txt', 'r');
fclose($handle);
```